# How can I create a Fluent NHibernate query that uses FetchMode.Select

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am simply trying to write a query that will look like this and be eager loaded:

```
Select * from Users where Id IN (1,2,3)
Select * from Bids where UserId in (1,2,3)
```

Right now it's causing problems because the join is returning too many results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using multicriteria (or Future as in this example), should issue 2 queries in 1 batch and give you the eager loading:

```
        var bids = Session.QueryOver<Bid>()
            .JoinQueryOver(b => b.User)
            .WhereRestrictionOn(u => u.Id).IsIn(ids)
            .Future<Bid>();
        var users = Session.QueryOver<User>()
            .WhereRestrictionOn(u => u.Id).IsIn(ids)
            .List<User>();
```

The only problem is it will join Bid -> User, to avoid that you could use HQL:

```
        var bids = Session.CreateQuery("from Bid b where b.User.id in (:userIds)")
            .SetParameterList("userIds", ids)
            .Future<Bid>();
        var users = Session.QueryOver<User>()
            .WhereRestrictionOn(u => u.Id).IsIn(ids)
            .List<User>();
```

Comment: For the first one, I do not think you have to join in order to where over IDs, it will just know what to do with it. I'll test it thank you.

Comment: .Where(u => u.Id).IsIn(ids) that doesn't work. .Where only uses a bool. What is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: should've been WhereRestrictionOn(u => u.Id).IsIn(ids)

Comment: You just copied the same thing, its actually .Where(u => u.Id.IsIn(ids))

Comment: with all due respect, .Where(u => u.Id).IsIn(ids) is not the same as .WhereRestrictionOn(u => u.Id).IsIn(ids)

Comment: You're right, didn't even notice that. But I used u.Id.IsIn. I still haven't checked the Sql for this yet but I think you answered it well.